# Change window location when rendering component with React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can i change window location when react component going to be rendered without use react router `<Route />` ?

```
                    {
                        this.state.loading ? 
                        ( <Loader percentageLoadingProgress={this.state.percentageLoadingProgress} loadingInformation={this.state.loadingInformation} /> ) : 
                        ( <Companies {...this.state} /> )
                    }
```

I need `<Companies />` to be rendered with changed window location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either return a `Redirect`, eg:

```
const someComponent = props => {
  if (props.foo) return `<Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />`;
  return <NormalUI />;
}
```

Or you can use the `useHistory` hook to get a `history` object, and then call `history.push('/somewhere/else')`:

```
const someComponent = props => {
  const history = useHistory();
  if (props.foo) history.push('/somewhere/else');
  else return <NormalUI />;
}
```

The `Redirect` component is the preferred way.